# zlib Z_DATA_ERROR "invalid code lengths set"

Tags: c, gzip, zlib, inflate

It used to work. I have a program that GETs and inflates the gzipped facebook page data.
Something has changed of late with the data I reiceve so that part way into the inflation I get an error Z_DATA_ERROR with the message "invalid code lengths set"
If I try to recover using inflateSync, upon trying inflate again I immediately get the data error again.

The deflated data is [here](http://compuclub.net/share/gzip.txt)

Looking at other sites I don't get this error, it could be something specific to facebook's gzip compression

This has had me stumped for an embarrassing amount of time, I'd dearly like to know how to fix it, I would assume there's nothing wrong with the data if the browser handles it fine.

Comment: Are you sure it's not corrupt? That data crashes the zlib utilities on my machine.

Comment: Maybe it will be useful to give some info from where did you get that data, what do you mean by browser handles it fine?

Comment: I don't see how it could be corrupt... it's from the facebook server. Using openSSL i get the chunked HTTP, stick it together then inflate using inflateInit2(&strm, 16+MAX_WBITS); ... inflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deflated data you posted is corrupt.  There might be an error in your de-chunking.

Comment: Could you add more detail?

Comment: That's all there is to it.